# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Vector

Tags: java, user-interface, xpath, vector, xml-parsing

I have XML parsed data that I am trying to add into a DefaultTableModel.
The DefaultTableModel takes in Vectors or Object[] as argument according to the documentation.

But when I use a Vector I get this exception :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Vector
```

This is the class I am using to parse and add into the vector .

```
public class PropXMLParsing {

    static PropXMLParsing instance = null;

    private Vector<String> header = new Vector<String>();
    private Vector<String> data = new Vector<String>();

    public static PropXMLParsing getInstance() {

        if (instance == null) {

            instance = new PropXMLParsing();
            try {
                instance.ParserForObjectTypes();
            } catch (SAXException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        return instance;

    }

    public void ParserForObjectTypes() throws SAXException, IOException,
            ParserConfigurationException {

        try {
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(
                    "xmlFiles/CoreDatamodel.xml"));

            DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                    .newInstance();

            DocumentBuilder builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

            Document xmlDocument = builder.parse(file);

            XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

            String expression = "//prop/*";
            NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(
                    xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);
            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {

                System.out.println(nodeList.item(i).getFirstChild()
                        .getNodeValue());

                data.addElement(nodeList.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                header.addElement(nodeList.item(i).getFirstChild()
                        .getNodeValue());

            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Vector<String> getHeader() {

        return header;
    }

    public Vector<String> getData() {
        return data;
    }

}
```

And this last line of code is where it cast exception. This is from my GUI class :

```
model = new DefaultTableModel(PropXMLParsing.getInstance().getHeader(),
                PropXMLParsing.getInstance().getData());

        table = new JTable(model);
```

Help me please

Comment: Side note: When adding an exception to your question, it is good to mark the line, where it is thrown.

Answer (score 3):

According to [the javadoc for DefaultTableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#DefaultTableModel%28java.util.Vector,%20java.util.Vector%29), the data must be a `Vector<Vector<String>>`. Also, you've got the data and header backwards in the DefaultTableModel constructor arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Java Docs states for used Constructor of `DefaultTableModel` as:

```
public DefaultTableModel(Vector data,
                 Vector columnNames)

Constructs a DefaultTableModel and initializes the table by passing data and columnNames to the setDataVector method.

Parameters:
    data - the data of the table, a Vector of Vectors of Object values
    columnNames - vector containing the names of the new columns
```

And `setDataVector()` accepts `dataVector(i.e.first arguement)` as **`Vector of vectors of Object`** values

So In your case first arguement in constructor `(i.e. PropXMLParsing.getInstance().getHeader())` should be `Vector<Vector<String>>`

## UPDATE

**Sample Code**

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("DemoFrame");
    
    Vector<String> id = new Vector<String>();
    id.add("1");
    id.add("2");
    id.add("3");
    
    Vector<String> name = new Vector<String>();
    name.add("A");
    name.add("B");
    name.add("C");
    
    Vector<Vector<String>> dataVector = new Vector<Vector<String>>();
    dataVector.add(id);
    dataVector.add(name);
    
    Vector<String> header = new Vector<String>(2);
    header.add("ID");
    header.add("NAME");

    
    TableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(dataVector,header);

    JTable table = new JTable(model);

    frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
    frame.setSize(300, 200);
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

**In case any of your dataVector or header is null table will not be displayed**

Comment: If I change it to a Vector <Vector> it will complain on this line : data.addElement(nodeList.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue()); And say that the argument have to be a String.

Comment: your first arguement should be Vector<Vector<String>> not the second one

Comment: Aight it solved the exception but sti not displaying any data in the table.

Comment: yeh header is null : header : []. not getting data correctly. aight.

Comment: yeh I added model to the table.

Comment: Yeh I am using window builder so it should be set to the Jframe yes.

Comment: yes Its there ".addComponent(
                    table,
                    GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                    600,
                    Short.MAX_VALUE)))
          .addGap(133)));"

Comment: Its jsut the table is empty I can see the tqable but no data but I see in the console the data except the header is null but its with the code. It should stil view the data . header : []
data : [Site parameters, null, NULL, null, 0, null, 1, null, NULL, null, 10008,